# Multiple query data into single HTML-Table - only one row returns

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database

I want to display results from 4 querys into one single html-table (SQL Server 2012, PHP, HTML). I already can display the results from one database-table, but as soon as I start to query the other 3 tables it only returns one row from the first table.

The following code only has one query and works fine - it displays several information about patients (Name, Station, Room, Catheter, Personal-ID, Date of Catheter-Insertion..), at the moment there are three different patients at the table, therefore the html-table shows 3 rows:

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');

$today = date("d.m.y");
$yesterday = date("d.m.y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
$dbyesterday = date("d.m.y", time() - 2*(60 * 60 * 24));
?>

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px">
    <div id="table_admin" class="span7">
          <h3 id="name" style="color: orange">Visitenliste</h3>
         </br>

         <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">

                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th id="tc">Station</th>
                <th id="tc">Patientennummer</th>
                <th id="tc">Zimmer</th>
                <th id="tc">Name</th>
                <th id="tc">Katheterart</th>
                <th id="tc">Anlagedatum</th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $dbyesterday; ?></th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $yesterday; ?></th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $today; ?></th>
               </tr>
                </thead>


   <?php
require_once('server.php');


// DB-Query für die Visitenliste
$sql = "SELECT dbo.patients.Patientennummer, Vorname, Nachname, Station, Zimmer, Katheterart, Anlagedatum, VisTod FROM dbo.patients INNER JOIN dbo.cathinsert ON dbo.patients.Patientennummer = dbo.cathinsert.Patientennummer ORDER BY Station ASC, Zimmer ASC";

$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);

if($result === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo        ("<tr class=\"clickable-row\" data-href=\"visitact.php?Patientennummer=".$row["Patientennummer"]."\">");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Station"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Patientennummer"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Zimmer"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Vorname"]." ".$row["Nachname"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Katheterart"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["Anlagedatum"]."</td>");
    echo        ("<td>".$row["VisTod"]."</td></tr>");  

              }
            ?>


        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As a result, I have a table with 3 rows and all information I needed.
But as soon as I start adding more querys now, the additional information is displayed right, but only for the first row! Its the only row displayed at all. I really can't figure out, why this happens.
This is the code not working (all information is displayed right, even the information from the additional querys, but only one row --> only the first patient, although 3 are saved at the database and although the first code displays all 3 patients in the right way):

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');
$today = date("d.m.y");
$yesterday = date("d.m.y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
$dbyesterday = date("d.m.y", time() - 2*(60 * 60 * 24));
?>

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px">
<div id="table_admin" class="span7">
       <h3 id="name" style="color: orange">Visitenliste</h3>
        </br>
         <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">

               <thead>
                <tr>
                <th id="tc">Station</th>
                <th id="tc">Patientennummer</th>
                <th id="tc">Zimmer</th>
                <th id="tc">Name</th>
                <th id="tc">Katheterart</th>
                <th id="tc">Anlagedatum</th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $dbyesterday; ?></th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $yesterday; ?></th>
                <th id="tc"><?php echo $today; ?></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

<?php
require_once('server.php');



// DB-Query für die Visitenliste

$sql = "SELECT dbo.patients.Patientennummer, Vorname, Nachname, Station, Zimmer, Katheterart, Anlagedatum FROM dbo.patients INNER JOIN dbo.cathinsert ON dbo.patients.Patientennummer = dbo.cathinsert.Patientennummer ORDER BY Station ASC, Zimmer ASC";
$visdbyes = "SELECT (SELECT VisiteKind FROM dbo.visits WHERE VisiteDate = '$dbyesterday') AS VisiteKind";
$visyes = "SELECT (SELECT VisiteKind FROM dbo.visits WHERE VisiteDate = '$yesterday') AS VisiteKind";
$vistod = "SELECT (SELECT VisiteKind FROM dbo.visits WHERE VisiteDate = '$today') AS VisiteKind";

$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
$result_vdy = sqlsrv_query($connection, $visdbyes);
$result_vy = sqlsrv_query($connection, $visyes);
$result_vt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $vistod);

$data = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){$data['row'] = $row;}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_vdy, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {$data['dby'] = $row;}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_vy, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {$data['yes'] = $row;}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_vt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {$data['tod'] = $row;}

echo    ("<tr class=\"clickable-row\" data-href=\"visitact.php?Patientennummer=".$row["Patientennummer"]."\">");  
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Station"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Patientennummer"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Zimmer"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Vorname"]." ".$data['row']["Nachname"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Katheterart"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['row']["Anlagedatum"]."</td>");
echo    ("<td>".$data['dby']["VisiteKind"]."</td>"); //vorgestern
echo    ("<td>".$data['yes']["VisiteKind"]."</td>"); // gestern
echo    ("<td>".$data['tod']["VisiteKind"]."</td>"); //heute
                    ?>

       </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hop you can help!
Thanks in advance,

dirk

Comment: So what do you expect? You iterate over each result independently. In the end you have only last value.

Comment: Maybe I need to clear out: dbo.patients contains a set of information for every single patient, everyone has only one row. Additionally, I have to visit them once a day, saving this information at dbo.visits. Every day a new bunch on information is stored there, same PatientID, but here multiple entrys (one for each day). Now I need to display the column 'VisiteKind' from dbo.visits from the last 3 days - and tgis is what I cant archieve, because the code above does post PatientInformation and the last 3 days right - but only for the first patient at dbo. patients.

Comment: You only assign the result to the same variable in a loop. In the end, you _once_ print the content of that variable which got overwritten multiple times and now only contains the last result. You should use a `join` across these tables and process the result set

Comment: But doesn't fetch_array loops through all rows until all rows at db.patients are seen and then the array turns false and the rest is executed? Is their a change in code avaiable to keep it the way it is? Beause it actually works fine - besides its only one row returning =).

Comment: @Psi: Thank you for your hint. But I can't figure out, how JOIN could help me out. It is because those 'VisiteKind' has numerous values, sometimes one per day, sometimes three per day (depends on the counts I visit the patients) and all those data is stored with a VisiteDate. I really cant see how JOIN could distinguish that and help me to print the latest VisiteKind per day for the last 3 days :(.

Comment: Then you need to use nested loops. While processing one records of the "main" query, issue subsequent queries for that record and process them altogether. Be careful not to use the same result set (otherwise your outer loop will terminate again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should use one query for every days, then check dates in while loop. You can also reduce 'VisiteKind' field in $data array:

```
$visd = "SELECT VisiteKind FROM dbo.visits";
$result_v = sqlsrv_query($connection, $visd);
$data = ['dby'=> [], 'yes'=> [], 'tod'=> []];
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_v, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    switch($row['VisiteKind']){
        case $dbyesterday:
            array_push($data['dby'],$row['VisiteKind']);
            break;
        case $yesterday:
            array_push($data['yes'],$row['VisiteKind']);
            break;
        case $today:
            array_push($data['tod'],$row['VisiteKind']);
            break;
    }
}
```